# How to move the image onto the next row in html/css

Tags: html, image, css

I am doing a class project for my uni but I cant seemed to solve this issue. Any kind help would be greatly appreciated! Basically I wanted to display a menu but the images keep overlapping. I want the image to be display on the next row. The idea is to make 4 images on one row and the next 4 images on the next row.

My hmtl code :

```css
.box {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
}

.box img {
  height: 220px;
  width: 360px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="Dim Sum" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Dim Sum</h3>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" />
    <div>小笼包 Chinese Dumpling Buns</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" />
    <div>叉烧包 BBQ Pork Buns</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" />
    <div>流沙包 Salted Egg Yoke Custard Lava Buns</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" />
    <div>豆沙包 Red Bean Buns</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" />
    <div>黑芝麻包 Black Sesame Buns</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Why you set the box height to 50px?

Comment: Actually i copy the source code format from the internet , so I have no idea. Is it the cause of the problem?

Comment: `Actually i copy the source code format from the internet, so I have no idea` --> in other words, here is a dummy code i found so please correct it for me ! ... why not simply take time to understand the code and then adjust it

Comment: I had been trying different methods to put images with captions and this is the one which I am closest to solving this question. I DID try to solve it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you have in mind:

```css
.box {
  margin-right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  display:inline-block;
}

.box img {
  height: 220px;
  width: 360px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Tab content -->
<div id="Dim Sum" class="tabcontent">
  <h3>Dim Sum</h3>
  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" />
    <div>小笼包 Chinese Dumpling Buns</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" />
    <div>叉烧包 BBQ Pork Buns</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" />
    <div>流沙包 Salted Egg Yoke Custard Lava Buns</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" />
    <div>豆沙包 Red Bean Buns</div>
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" />
    <div>黑芝麻包 Black Sesame Buns</div>
  </div>
```

I have used [`inline-block`](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block.html) for attaining this result.